# Sequel Migrator Not Defined

Tags: ruby, database-migration, sequel

I'm trying to run some migrations on a database via Sequel's `Sequel::Migrator`. However, when I run...

```
DB = Sequel.sqlite
Sequel::Migrator.apply DB, 'db/migrations'
```

I got the following error.

> uninitialized constant Sequel::Migrator

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays `Sequel::Migrator` is not included by default. This means that you just can't `require 'sequel'` and be able to start using `Sequel::Migrator` right away.

Instead you have to load the migration and core extensions provided by Sequel like so.

```
Sequel.extension :migration, :core_extensions
```

Now if you check whether `Sequel::Migrator` is defined Ruby should return `"constant"`.

```
1.9.3 :001 > Sequel.extension :migration, :core_extensions
 => [:migration, :core_extensions]
1.9.3 :002 > defined? Sequel::Migrator
 => "constant"
```